# Trigger one repo ci inside another repo

Tags: github, azure-pipelines

I have two repos under the same organization on github that depend on each other. Repo B is a submodule in Repo A and I would like to run Repo A's azure.yml against any pull requests to repo B. I want a pull request to B to essentially clone A and replace the submodule and run the pipeline for A and report the results back to B. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create two pipelines. One is for Repo B, another is for Repo A. Adding a REST API task in the pipeline for Repo B to trigger the pipeline for Repo A. Once the pull request trigger the pipeline for Repo B, this pipeline will trigger the pipeline for Repo A.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1